# $x \in \mathbb Q , 0 \ne y \in \mathbb R$ , $\lim_{n \to \infty} (yx^n-m_n)=0$ , $\{m_n\}$ a sequence of positive integers , then is $x$ an integer?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $x$ be a rational number and $y$ be a non-zero real number and $\{m_n\}$ be a sequence of positive integers such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (yx^n-m_n)=0$ ; then is it true that $x$ is an integer ?

Comment: Good question. To start with: $x$ cannot be between $-1$ and $1$, or else $yx^n \to 0$. $x$ also cannot be negative; otherwise, the sign of $yx^n$ would altenate. I'm kind of puzzled where to go from there.

Comment: When you say "positive integers", do you also include $0$?

Comment: @AlexM. Positive means "strictly positive."

Comment: I don't think this assertion is true: Take $m_n=\lfloor yx^n\rfloor$, which is probably the closest you can get by choosing $m_n$ as a positive integer (exchange floor by ceiling, if you wish). Since $y$ can be irrational, the limit need not even exist.

Comment: @Bernhard The OP didn't claim it to hold for every sequence $m_n$.

Comment: @uniquesolution: Right, but that it holds for one sequence. I just assumed that for this one sequence one should have either $m_n\in\{\lfloor yx^n\rfloor,\lceil yx^n\rceil$. In fact, in order to have a limit being equal to zero, eventually one should be able to make sure that the fractional part of $yx^n$ converges to zero. This need not be the case, however, if $y$ is irrational.

Comment: @uniquesolution: Did the first part, the second, more complicated part is still missing. I'll try to work it out!

Answer (score 1):

First, $y$ cannot be irrational: To see this, note that either $m_n=\lfloor yx^n\rfloor$ or $m_n=\lceil yx^n\rceil$ minimizes $|yx^n-m_n|$; By the irrationality of $y$, however, the remainder of this subtraction will not converge to zero with increasing $n$. Hence, $y\in\mathbb{Q}$.

That is just the first part of the proof, there is still something left to do. However, we now know that $y=q/p$. If $x=p$, then $yx^n=qp^{n-1}$ is integer and by choosing $m_n=qp^{n-1}$ the limit is zero. It remains to show that also the converse holds.